# rsync --include option does not exclude other files

Tags: bash, rsync

trying to rsync files of certain extension(*.sh), but the bash script below still transfer all the files, why?

```
from=/home/xxx
rsync -zvr --include="*.sh" $from/*  root@$host:/home/tmp/
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add a --exclude all and it has to come after the --include

```
rsync -zvr --include="*.sh" --exclude="*" $from/*  root@$host:/home/tmp/
```

Comment: Good point about the recursion, @that. On OS X, it appears that the exclude(s) have to follow the include(s).  I would have thought that **find . -name '\*.sh' | rsync -zvr --include-from=- --exclude='*' ...** would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: As noted the answer from @that is better, as you need the --include="*/" to include subdirectories

Comment: I tried this and it transfers no data. Also tried using exclude before and after my include statements and it produces the same result.

Answer (score 24):

`--include` is for which files you want to not `--exclude`. Since you haven't excluded any in future arguments, there's no effect. You can do:

```
from=/home/xxx
rsync -zvr --include="*.sh" --include="*/" --exclude="*" "$from" root@$host:/home/tmp/
```

To recursively copy all .sh files (the extra `--include` to not skip directories that could contain .sh files)

Comment: I think the exclude is in the wrong place; it should be after the includes. Rsync acts on the first matching pattern.

Comment: Hipponax43 is right: could you correct your answer, because me and surely other users have been having a bad time trying to use your wrong answer

Comment: You may add **--prune-empty-dirs** to skip directories that are empty (not matching any files).

Answer (score 7):

On thing to add, at least on my machines (FreeBSD and OS X), this does not work:

```
rsync -aP --include=*/ --include=*.txt --exclude=* * /path/to/dest
```

but this does:

```
rsync -aP --include=*/ --include=*.txt --exclude=* . /path/to/dest
```

Yes, wildcarding the current directory seem to override the exclude.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed the problem changing **--exclude=*** by **--exclude=*.***, I understand that * exclude folder where include files are.

Comment: What if you have a foldername containing a dot, ex: "backup.12"  ?