# How to filter files by extension with Perl File::RsyncP

Tags: perl

I am using Perl library File::RsyncP.

This moment script copies all files, but I need to use
extension and later pattern for example 2019*.xml

I don´t know how to filter files by extension.
I have tried following

I take a connection into localhost
I have

```
/home/raimo/A/SRC/srcDirectory/1.xml
/home/raimo/A/SRC/srcDirectory/2.xml
/home/raimo/A/SRC/srcDirectory/3.txt
```

here
I would like to copy only xml files into

I have tried:

```
rsyncCmd => "/bin/rsync -avz --include '*.xml' srcDirectory destDirectory ", and I have tired rsyncCmd => "/bin/rsync -avz --include '*.xml' destDirectory srcDirectory "
```

/home/raimo/A/SRC/destDirectory

```
my $rs = File::RsyncP->new({
        logLevel   => 5,
        rsyncCmd   => "/bin/rsync --include '*.xml'",   #check if possible to filter
        rsyncArgs  => [
                "--numeric-ids",
                "--perms",
                "--owner",
                "--group",
                "--devices",
                "--links",
                "--ignore-times",
                "--block-size=700",
                "--relative",
                "--recursive",
                "--verbose"
            ],
    });
...
 # Receive files from remote srcDirectory to local destDirectory
 # # by running rsyncCmd with rsyncArgs.
 $rs->remoteStart(1, srcDirectory);
```

Comment: How would you exclude the files using a plain `rsync` command line?

Comment: Hi, I haven´t used plain rsync but, there is mentioned on internet pages. That following syntax should work /bin/rsync -avz --exclude '*.typ' source/ destination/. With perl library that I I am using. source and destination has to write elsewhere... # Receive files from remote srcDirectory to local destDirectory<br>
 # # by running rsyncCmd with rsyncArgs. 
  $rs->remoteStart(1, srcDirectory); 
 #
  $rs->go(destDirectory);
 #

Comment: So, maybe follow what the internet pages suggest?

Comment: ok, after pause, I try to write source and destination, into both places after rsync command. and into libraries place... Now I take a pause of one hour

Comment: `--include '*.pl' --exclude '*'` -  you first include all `.pl` files, but then exclude all files - that makes little sense. Maybe explain which files you want to include and which files you want to exclude and show some examples.

Comment: my purpose is include \*.xml files   I have tried: rsyncCmd   => "/bin/rsync -avz --include '\*.xml' srcDirectory destDirectory ",  and I have tired rsyncCmd   => "/bin/rsync -avz --include '\*.xml' destDirectory srcDirectory ",..

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the above comment to it? Maybe also add some example directory structure and explain what `rsync` does and also what you want it to do?

Comment: hi, I don´t have enough points for chat. I have updated my question

Comment: Are there other files in `/home/raimo/A/SRC/srcDirectory/` that you want to avoid? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655834/rsync-include-option-does-not-exclude-other-files shows that your first approach should be what you want, `--include '*.xml' --exclude '*'`

Comment: exclude is not necessary, only files what match for example with filename2019*.xml. my filename variable comes... word +wildcard +extension (xml) in this case. problem is that File::RsyncP; does not react to --include '*.xml'...instead it copies all files in a directory

Comment: Try adding `--include` and `*.xml` to the `rsyncArgs`, not the `rsyncCmd`.

Comment: I have tried already.  rsyncArgs  => [
                    "--numeric-ids",
                    "--perms",
                    "--owner",
                    "--group",
                    "--devices",
                    "--links",
                    "--ignore-times",
                    "--block-size=700",
                    "--relative",
                    "--recursive",
                    "--verbose",
     "--include '*.xml'",. causes an error Fatal error (bad version): rsync: on remote machine: --include '\*.xml': unknown option

Comment: Split it up: `"--include", "*.xml"`

Comment: ok, I did it. now it copies all files but not xml.Can't chmod(destDirectory/test.xml, 0100777)
Can't chown(1000, 1000, destDirectory/test.xml)
Can't mtime(1547135663, 1547135663, destDirectory/test.xml)

Comment: test.xml was empty, I filled it. test.xml is copied also, but so are all files

Comment: exclude txt works perfectly now, but include not work with patterns, you have helped me alot, If I could do filter by pattern, I could maybe put this little by little into production."--include", "*.xml",
     "--exclude", "*.txt",